# CPU Stays at 25% Sometimes - Immense Lag

Tags: laptop, cpu, performance, cpu-usage, lag

When I run heavy applications such as a game or multiple instances of something, my computer lags a lot. My task manager only shows that I am using 25 percent of CPU (keep in mind that all of the cpu combined is only 25%)- when it goes back to 100-80% it is perfectly fine. I find this sus because I have a quad core cpu suggesting that only one core is running?

It is really annoying when I play a game because when my **ENTIRE** CPU caps at 25%, I lag really hard, and after about a minute it goes back to normal (about 80-100% of CPU), then I can play perfectly fine. It just goes on and off all the time.

**Specs**:

Lenovo Thinkpad:

4 GB RAM

Intel(R) Core(TM) m3-7Y30 CPU @ 1 GHz (quad core)

Intel(R) HD Graphics 615

Comment: What game? Is the high CPU all in the game process, or are there other processes using substantial amounts of CPU? This is a very low power computer. Lag should be rather expected I believe. Though learning why could help minimize its impact.

Comment: @music2myear all games, especially 3d. But remember it isn't just games, sometimes when I have a ton of tabs open as well. No other processes is causing the issue too.

Comment: Check disk I/O too -- if it's heavy, it prevents processes making full use of CPU.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik when I check disk for task manager, it only shows 0.1%

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly an IO bottleneck - and Id put my money on you using a hard disk, or an SSS that is old/failing.

What is happening is everything is waiting on disk, so your processor is not needed as much as it otherwise would.

Also pointing that disk IO is the likely cause is the specs of the system. Very broadly speaking systems with 4 gigs of RAM were released when SSDs were in their infancy - meaning a HDD - which is a typical bottleneck - is common.  Many of the tiny SSDs of the time have also become very slow.

Get Crystal Disk Mark and check your IO.  If its less the  150 meganytes/sec chances are you have an hdd or end-of-life SSD - replacing it will do your system a world of good.